# Django: does the ORM support the SQL "IN" operator?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Does the Django ORM support the SQL `IN` operator? Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE id IN (1, 5, 34, 567, 229)
```

How do I use the Django ORM to make a query like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

## [in](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 5, 34, 567, 229])

print _.query
SELECT <fields> FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" IN (1, 5, 34, 567, 229)
```

Comment: In will not allow us to print the objects in the order the list is provided. It will return the objects as it matches the elements in the list.

Answer (score 7):

Beside that, Django ORM also support for Sub-Query:

For example:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery
users = User.objects.all()
UserParent.objects.filter(user_id__in=Subquery(users.values('id')))
```

Comment: Is there a limit to how many elements i can put in the in clause?

Comment: What's the point of using Subquery without OuterRef?

Answer (score 0):

as Yuji indicates above <field_name>__in=[<list_of_values>] is translated to the following SQL:

WHERE <field_name> IN (<list_of_values>)

you can find the complete reference of django SQL WHERE operators under the **Field lookups** section of the following Django API document.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/